# When should I choose lambdas over function pointers in C++11?

Tags: c++11, lambda, function-pointers

A lambda function can be inlined in the source code. They are useful to pass these procedures as parameters to other modules. However, this can also be achieved through function pointers. Is there any set of good practices or rules of thumb regarding When should I choose lambdas over function pointers in C++11?

Comment: Might you have an example? And is there a reason you did not consider asking the question for function objects (or functors)?

Comment: @Elyasin I have no example, since I intended for this to be a general question.

Comment: And what abou the second question if I may ask?

Comment: @Elyasin: I wanted to keep the question as simple and straightforward as possible.

Comment: I see. I mentioned function objects (functors) aside in my answer though. Consider reading about those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Chose lambda expression over pointer to function.**

I think you should not choose function pointers. Instead, in C++11 you have function objects and lambdas, a lambda being considered an anonymous local function object (though no two lambda expressions are equal; they don't have return types; they are closure types).

I consider them a technical legacy from C that C++ supports. Unless you are working with C or legacy code you might as well consider not to pay too much attention to function pointers.

- A pointer to function can be cast to a different pointer-to-function type.
- A lambda has access to its scope's variables, which you can specify in the capture list.
- A lambda can outlive its caller (pass lambda to different thread, or stored for later usage). And this can be a problem when local variables are captured inappropriately (i.e. by reference).
- The argument list of a lambda can be omitted. I.e. the shortest lambda is `[]{}`.
- A lambda expression's return type can be deduced from its body.

When small and used only once: lambda
When not small or reused: function object

Comment: So, for a jump table, you'd use an array of `std::function` instead of an array of function pointers?  For type erasure, you'd store everything operation in `std::function`s?  How would you implement a move-only variant of `std::function`?  For everyday use, I agree with your thought: but treating function pointers as technical legacy only is ... too much.

Comment: Maybe you are right; I don't know in that case exactly. I think I would see if *pointers to function members* would be helpful. If I had to design I'd probably go that way.

Answer (score 4):

A lambda expression can capture variables, creating a closure type that has data associated with it. You can't bind data to a function pointer, the function can only operate on its parameters and global data.

Answer (score 1):

If your lambda expression is more than a few lines (three?) it could be good to make a function out of it.